# Error on search, With automation error

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a bit of code know that works with pulling information from a cell and paste it into a search engine to search. Which works fine as a tested on both google and bing pulls back what I want to search.

Now I've changed the code which I think is correct to an internal website but now get and run-time error and automation error. It will load the site fine, Just not search through it.

I'm no expert at this so still trying to learn VBA. Also if you can advise any pointers on the best way to troubleshoot things likes.

As at the moment, the only way I figure it out is to break each line see what it does and find the fault. But this is a bit beyond me.

The only thing I think it could be but might be wrong is missing a reference

I've got the HTML Object library and Internet controls.

[Run time error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFmXF.png)

This is the code from the site for the search box.

```
<input class="genInput" type="text" size="32" name="xx_quicksearch" value="" id="quicksearchbox">
```

This is my code,

```
Sub Test()
Dim ie As Object
Dim form As Variant
Dim button As Variant
Dim LR As Integer
Dim var As String
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To LR
var = Cells(x, 1).Value
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.Visible = True
With ie
.Visible = True
.navigate "*******"
While Not .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Wend
End With
'Wait some to time for loading the page
 While ie.Busy
 DoEvents
Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
ie.document.getElementById("quicksearch").Value = var
'code to click the button
 Set form = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("form")
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
 Set button = form(0).onsubmit
 form(0).submit
 'wait for page to load
While ie.Busy
DoEvents
Wend
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id is different from what you posted. In: `ie.document.getElementById("quicksearch").Value = var` try typing `"quicksearchbox"` rather than just `"quicksearch"`

Comment: My Bad that was where I was testing forgot to revert it back to the original word. I'm Still in countering the error though.

Comment: Ok. If you can tell people which line it is failing I'm sure it would help get you an answer

Comment: It seems to error on line 16, Which is the Wend. Or my guessing is the site isn't reporting back complete yet before it jumps to the next command?

Comment: figured it out. It is the option within IE, Needs to enable protected mode for some reason.

Comment: Interesting. Glad you figured it out. What helped you arrive at your answer?

Comment: It was really with trial and error and a bit off googling and trying results to see what worked.